# [__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, nstimer, ios8

```
    var searchDelayer:NSTimer?
    func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar!, textDidChange searchText: String!) {
        searchDelayer?.invalidate()
        searchDelayer = nil

        searchDelayer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.5, target: self, selector: Selector("doDelayedSearch:"), userInfo: searchText, repeats: false)

    }

    func doDelayedSearch(text:String){
    ...
    }
```

Why this code crashes with error message:

```
[__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Updated:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9c622ae7e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c05b3e5 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010ba42967 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010c0624fd -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bfba7ec ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bfba388 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf32935 CFStringCreateCopy + 229
    6   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x000000010dc41314 _TF10Foundation24_convertNSStringToStringFCSo8NSStringSS + 116
    7   MapCode                             0x000000010a1a567e _TToFC7MapCode17MapViewController15doDelayedSearchfS0_FSST_ + 62
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010b5fce94 __NSFireTimer + 83
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bfc34d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bfc3095 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1045
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf863cd __CFRunLoopRun + 1901
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010bf859f6 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    13  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ecfd9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010c96b990 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    15  MapCode                             0x000000010a1b3fee top_level_code + 78
    16  MapCode                             0x000000010a1b402a main + 42
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010f9d7145 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: I have deleted my answer because it apparently does not help. - Thinking about it again, the problem must be related to the timer itself, and not to the target. Can you set an "Exception Breakpoint" and then post the stack backtrace when the exception occurs?

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. Please see updated post. When exception breakpoint is set, then app crashes in AppDelegate.swift, on line ```class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate```

Comment: Can you step through in the debugger and verify what line is causing the crash.  The stack trace looks as if it's inside `doDelayedSearch`, trying to copy a string and finding an unexpected timer object instead.

Comment: The timer callback must not have a `String` argument. Will update my answer in a minute ...

Comment: doDelayedSearch is not called. Crash happens when NSTimer calls it.

Comment: I think @MartinR is right about ```String``` argument, however I can't understand how to do workaround.

Comment: @Shmidt: Give me some minutes, still updating answer ...

Comment: @MartinR Thanks. I understood now from your answer I can call function without arguments. Will try now.

Comment: Ah...then probably the string it thinks it's copying at `CFStringCreateCopy + 229` is the input parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The timer callback function must be either a function without arguments, or
a function taking a `NSTimer` as a single argument.

In your case, it should be

```
func doDelayedSearch(timer: NSTimer) {
    let searchText = timer.userInfo as String
    // ...
}
```

---

*Old answer:* (The following is correct but does not apply here)

The target of the timer (`self` in your case) needs to be compatible with Objective-C,
i.e. derived from `NSObject` or marked with `@objc`.

See also 
[Exposing Swift Interfaces in Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html) in the 
"Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C" documentation (emphasis mine):

> The `@objc` attribute makes your Swift API available in Objective-C and
>   the Objective-C runtime. In other words, you can use the `@objc`
>   attribute before any Swift method, property, subscript, initializer,
>   or class that you want to use from Objective-C code. If your class
>   inherits from an Objective-C class, the compiler inserts the attribute
>   for you.
>   ...
>   This attribute is also useful when you’re working with
>   Objective-C classes **that use selectors to implement the target-action design pattern—for example, `NSTimer`** or `UIButton`.

Comment: In my case self is of ```UIViewController``` class. I marked it as ```@objc``` but crash still happens.